# large boundaries of a polynomial solutions set

Tags: algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods

if I assume that polynomial solutions in $R$ may be only the results of operations +  -  * and / of the coefficients and the powers  , I'm wondering if it is possible to bound the absolute values of the solutions of a polynomial by a function of its coefficients and its powers. Of course, powers are extensions of the product.

The boundaries formula or algorithm, even if large, must work for any polynomial of any order ( max power ).

Why ? when I see $-x^7 + 16 x^2 - 4x -5 = 0$ , my intuition says me that never the solution will be $|x| = 1525444448743215$ ; it is too big ...

May we do better and safer than intuition, possibly based on theorems ? or on some well known conjecture ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [root bounds exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_polynomial_roots#Bounds_on_.28complex.29_polynomial_roots). For instance, with the leading coefficient $a_n=1$,
$$
R=\max(1,|a_{n-1}|+…+|a_1|+|a_0|
$$
and
$$
R=1+\max(|a_{n-1}|,…,|a_1|,|a_0|)
$$
are such bounds.

The second bound tells you that the solution will be smaller in absolute value than $17$.

Using $f(2w)=-128w^7+64w^2−8w−5=128(-w^7+\tfrac12w^2-\tfrac1{16}w-\tfrac5{128})$ gives a bound of $\frac32$ for $w$ and thus $3$ for $x$.

Comment: very very interesting, I was waiting largest bounds. Is it based on a theorem on or something easy to show ? TY

Comment: You can use the Rouche theorem, or the Gershgorin circle theorem for the companion matrix, or you can prove these estimates with elementary computations.

Comment: When $a_0\ne 0$ : Letting $x=1/y$  and $f(x)=y^n g(y),$  we also obtain a lower bound on $|x|$ for  solutions of  $f(x)=0.$

Comment: @igael. The second upper bound $R=1+\max (|a_0|,...,|a_{n-1}|)=1+M$  is quite easy.  When $|x|\geq R$ we have $|\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_jx^j|\leq$ $ M\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}|x|^j=$ $M(|x|^n-1)/(|x|-1)\leq$ $ M(|x|^n-1)/M=|x^n|-1<|x|^n.$ (...The case $M=0$ is trivial as then the polynomial is  just $x^n.$ )

Comment: @user254665 I'm puzzled by the narrowness of the boundaries. It's very usefull to limit brute force for integer solutions of polynomials. And more. TY all !

Comment: @igael.What are  you puzzled by?   ... BTW: In your example, let $x=ky$ with $k> 0.$ Then  $f(x)= -x^7+16x^2-4x-5=$ $-k^7(y^7-16y^2/k^5+4y/k^6+5/k^7).$  So if $f(x)=0$ then $|y|<1+\max (16/k^5,4/k^6,5/k^7),$  so $|x|=k|y|<k+\max (16/k^4,4/k^5,5/k^6.)$  With $k=2$ this gives $|x|<3.$